# GUI won't appear despite compiling runner file

Tags: java, user-interface

My assignments require that we write a "runner" file that is opened by the original project file and it's only when the project file is run that my runner file does not create a GUI, otherwise running the runner file by itself does.

Teacher included the feedback that I had not included my event handling code but I'm not sure what I'm missing at this point.

This is the program I do not interfere with:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    new Proj05Runner();
  }//end main
}//end class Proj05
```

And this is my runner code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Proj05Runner extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GUI gui = new GUI();
    }
}

class GUI extends JFrame{
    public GUI(){//constructor
    //Create a new Frame object
    JFrame displayWindow = new JFrame();
    displayWindow.setSize(300,200);
    displayWindow.setTitle("Brendan");
    //Button button1 = new Button("Press");
    //Instantiate two Listener objects that will process
    // Window events
    WProc1 winProcCmd1 = new WProc1(displayWindow);
    WProc2 winProcCmd2 = new WProc2();

    //Register the Listener objects for notification of
    // Window events. This object is the Event Source.
    displayWindow.addWindowListener(winProcCmd1);
    displayWindow.addWindowListener(winProcCmd2);

    //windowActivated and windowOpened test messages
    // are produced here
    displayWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class WProc1 implements WindowListener{
  //used to save a reference to the Frame object
  JFrame displayWindowRef;

  WProc1(JFrame windowIn){//constructor
    // save ref to JFrame object
    this.displayWindowRef = windowIn;
  }//end constructor

  public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println("WProc1 windowClosed test msg");
  }//end windowClosed()

  public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println("WProc1 windowIconified test msg");
  }//end windowIconified()

  public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println("WProc1 windowOpened test msg");
  }//end windowOpened()

  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println("WProc1 windowClosing test msg");
    displayWindowRef.dispose();//generate WindowClosed
  }//end windowClosing()

  public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println(
                      "WProc1 windowDeiconified test msg");
  }//end windowDeiconified()

  public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println("WProc1 windowActivated test msg");
  }//end windowActivated()

  public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println(
                     "WProc1 windowDeactivated test msg");
  }//end windowDeactivated()
}//end class WProc1
//=======================================================//

//This and the previous class can be used to instantiate
// Listener objects. Note that this class extends an
// Adapter class that can be used to avoid the
// requirement to define all of the methods of the
// actual Listener class named WindowListener. This class
// overrides only two of the methods declared in the
// interface.  It displays a message whenever one of the
// methods is called.
class WProc2 extends WindowAdapter{

  public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println(
              "******** WProc2 windowIconified test msg");
  }//end windowIconified()

  public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println(
            "******** WProc2 windowDeiconified test msg");
  }//end windowDeiconified()

}//end class WProc2
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I don't understand why you expect your GUI to appear. You create the GUI in a `main` method, but you don't call that, you just call an unrelated constructor.

Comment: In your ProJ05Runner, remove the main part and add a constructor instead that calls new GUI();

Answer (score 0):

Proj05Runner has a static main method and no constructor, but when you invoke `new Proj05Runner();` you are not invoking that main method but a default constructor.

You have to possible solutions, changing that line for `Proj05Runner.main(args);` or changing Proj05Runner main method by an empty constructor:

```
public Proj05Runner(){
    GUI gui = new GUI();
}
```

By the way, if you are using JDK10 or greater, you may use the var keyword: `var gui = new GUI();`